# Turbo C++ program that's counting occurrences of a string in data file is always (incorrectly) returning zero.

Tags: c++

I wrote a program in Turbo C++ counting the number of occurrences of the string "HOTEL" in a data file. But it's always giving me the value 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
//PROGRAM TO COUNT NO OF OCCURENCES OF A STRING IN A DATA FILE
#include<fstream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
ifstream ifs;
ifs.open("DATA.DOCX",ios::in|ios::nocreate);
if (!ifs)
 { 
    cout<<"SORRY! FILE DOES NOT EXIST";
 }   
else
 {
int count=0;
char compare[20];
while (ifs.eof())
 {
    ifs>>compare;
    if (strcmp(compare,"HOTEL")==0)
     count++;
 }
ifs.close();
cout<<"NO OF OCCURENCE OF STRING 'HOTEL' = "<<count;
  }
getch();
}
```

Comment: Is the file `"DATA.DOCX"` in MS Word format? If so, it will be a difficult task.

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT. *Edit*: I've removed the shouting for you, and other irrelevancies. Please look at the edit so you know what to do for next time. More details about what you think is wrong would also be good.

Comment: Have you tried using a plain text file?

Comment: Examine the condition in your loop closely. And use text files, not MS Word files.

Comment: I wrote a program using ___CAPS LOCK ON___

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `while ( !ifs.eof() )`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp [Not really](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Well I see from your question and your code that you love caps lock... `if (strcmp(compare,"HOTEL")==0)` does your data file also shout? because if not, you might need to use `strcmpi()` to get a case insensitive version of string compare. Also, what did your debugger do when you hit a string compare that you thought should return that they  are the same?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes and no, yes the condition is inverted, no you shouldn't use .eof() as a loop condition (πάντα ῥεῖ beat me to it)

Comment: Turbo C++ is ancient. You should work with a new compiler. And use `std::string`. And have `main` return `int`.

Comment: @MikeCAT  , What's the problem with MS WORD files?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , What's shouting? Sorry But I did not understand

Comment: @Abhimanyu: On the 'net (and most other places), ALL CAPS is shouting. Surely if you just looked at my edit, and my comment, that was fairly obvious?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder . OK Thanks . But any help regarding the program?

Comment: @Abhimanyu: There's all sorts of help above.

Comment: @Abhimanyu:  Microsoft Word **data** files are not in simple text.  The contain other information, such as fonts and attributes (bolding, italic, etc) used by each word and letter, as well as other stuff.  If you want to read MS Word files, please search internet for "MSDN read word file c++".

Comment: @RyanP , There's no shouting in my data file . I have checked it. But it still does not work.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I changed my file name to "DATA.TXT" and now its working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As asker has said, the issue was that the file name was "DATA.DOCX" and needed to be changed to "DATA.TXT".

```
//PROGRAM TO COUNT NO OF OCCURENCES OF A STRING IN A DATA FILE
#include<fstream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
ifstream ifs;
ifs.open("DATA.TXT",ios::in|ios::nocreate);
if (!ifs)
 { 
    cout<<"SORRY! FILE DOES NOT EXIST";
 }   
else
 {
int count=0;
char compare[20];
while (ifs.eof())
 {
    ifs>>compare;
    if (strcmp(compare,"HOTEL")==0)
     count++;
 }
ifs.close();
cout<<"NO OF OCCURENCE OF STRING 'HOTEL' = "<<count;
  }
getch();
}
```